# how to compare full databases in c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 SQL databases and I want to compare each and everything in it like no of tables, views, stored procedures, columns, primary keys etc. How do I do that programmatically, using C#?

Comment: I rather think it is. Don't simply decide what the best tool for OP is - ask why they want to do it in C#, and if there are other alternatives they might consider.

Comment: It is an entirely too *broad* question, however. So, OP, please explain what you've tried, what you're thinking, etc.

Comment: I'd use a tool such as Microsoft SSDT - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx - rather than reinventing the wheel

Comment: @J.Steen:agreed,but just wondering what is the real use of this

Comment: @Buzz That's definitely a more valid question. In this case, it'd be very nice if OP explained the reasoning behind wanting to use C# rather than a purpose-made tool. =)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27122/Side-by-Side-SQL-Comparer-in-C

Take a look at the link, it provides a good set of instructions to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to compare the databases form C#, there are lots of readymade tools available for this:

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool)

[Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com)

[DbCompare](http://dbcomparer.com/)